# Why is the "mail" command's option "-s" not working?

Tags: linux, email

when I use

```
mail root -s "subject" <~/.bashrc
```

it doesn't work. It just prompts me to input the subject as if I used `mail root`.
After I keyed in the content, ended it up with ' .' or Ctrl+D, it seems to recognize the `-s`, and so it reads

```
send-mail "invalid options --'s'
```

and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple programs behind the `mail` command on linux, but they should generally  accept the `-s` options. However, the ones I tested require the email addressee to come after the options. Try this command instead:

```
mail -s 'subject' root < ~/.bashrc
```

This syntax has always worked for me.